# Weak Law of Large Numbers using Minkowski's Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ be i.i.d. r.v.s such that for $1\leq j\leq n$, $E( X_j)=0$ and $$(E(|X_j|^p))^{1/p}=M<\infty$$ for some $1<p<2$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, and prove that for any $\delta >0$, $$P(|S_n/n|>\delta)\to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$. This yields the WLLN without the finite variance assumption.

I tried the following approach: Apply Markov's inequality to $|S_n|^p$, which gives
$$P(|S_n|^p \geq (\delta n)^p) = P(|S_n| \geq \delta n) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|S_n|^p]}{(\delta n)^p}$$

Since the (X_j)'s are i.i.d. with mean 0, use Minkowski's inequality:
$$ (\mathbb{E}[|S_n|^p])^{1/p} \leq \sum_{j=1}^n (\mathbb{E}[|X_j|^p])^{1/p} = nM. $$

This implies
$$ \frac{\mathbb{E}[|S_n|^p]}{(\delta n)^p} = \left( \frac{(\mathbb{E}[|S_n|^p])^{1/p}}{\delta n} \right)^p \leq \left( \frac{nM}{\delta n} \right)^p = \left( \frac{M}{\delta} \right)^p. $$

As $n \to \infty$,
$$ P\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n} \geq \delta\right) \leq \left( \frac{M}{\delta} \right)^p \cdot \frac{1}{n^{p-1}} \to 0$$
since $1 < p < 2$ implies $p-1 > 0$.

Thus, we have shown that $P\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right| > \delta\right) \to 0$ as required.

I'm not sure if Markov's inequality is the right approach to this problem or if there is a better measure theoretic approach. Any advice or correction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did $\frac 1 {n^{p-1}}$ appear from nowhere?

Comment: It comes from the normalization of $S_n$ by $n$ cause we're going  from the $p$-th power inequality to the original probability statement.

Comment: As far as I can see you only have $ P\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n} \geq \delta\right) \leq \left( \frac{M}{\delta} \right)^p $.

Comment: How do we connect that inequality to the desired result in that case? I would imagine bringing $n$ into the denominator of the right hand side of the inequality should be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you only got $P\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n} \geq \delta\right) \leq \left( \frac{M}{\delta} \right)^p$ which is not sufficient to conclude. A more fundamental reason for which it does not work is that you do not use independence.

A possible approach is to use truncation. Define for a fixed $n$ the random variables
$$
Y_{n,i}=X_i\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X_i\rvert\leqslant n^{1/p}}-\mathbb E\left[X_i\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X_i\rvert\leqslant n^{1/p}}\right],
$$
$$
Z_{n,i}=X_i\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X_i\rvert\gt n^{1/p}}-\mathbb E\left[X_i\mathbf{1}_{\lvert X_i\rvert\gt n^{1/p}}\right].
$$
Since each $X_i$ is centered, we have $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}+\sum_{i=1}^n Z_{n,i}$ and it suffices to prove that
$$
\frac 1{n^{1/p}}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{n,i}\to 0 \mbox{ in probability and} \frac 1{n^{1/p}}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_{n,i}\to 0 \mbox{ in probability}.
$$
For the first part, use Tchebychev inequality and for the second one, simply Markov's inequality.

Comment: Great approach! Thanks a lot!